# ¿Cómo cargar un Excel a SQL Server con PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, phpexcel

Cordial Saludo,

Les comento, necesito cargar un `excel` de aproximado 350.000 registros, y aproximado 60 campos, esto lo hago con `php` y no me los carga, ya que son bastante, me carga como 30.000, he configurado el `php.ini` a los recursos del servidor, pero no, es lo máximo que he podido llegar,

Utilizo `PHPExcel`:

```
$target_path = 'subidas/';
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['pacientes_file']['name']); 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pacientes_file']['tmp_name'], $target_path);

$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($target_path);
$ob

jReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($target_path);
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();  
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
$usuario = $_SESSION['CodUser'];
$usuario = trim($usuario);

for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 
  $cod_os = $sheet->getCell("A".$row)->getValue();
  $sucursal = $sheet->getCell("B".$row)->getValue();
  $nombre_os = $sheet->getCell("C".$row)->getValue();
  $nit_os = $sheet->getCell("D".$row)->getValue();
  $suc_prop_pac = $sheet->getCell("E".$row)->getValue();
  $cod_pac = $sheet->getCell("F".$row)->getValue();
  $nombre_pac = $sheet->getCell("G".$row)->getValue();
  $estado_pac = $sheet->getCell("H".$row)->getValue();
  $descripcion_motivo_baja = $sheet->getCell("I".$row)->getValue();
  $Descripcion_motivo_inhibicion = $sheet->getCell("J".$row)->getValue();

  $procedure_params = array(
    array(&$cod_os, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array(&$sucursal, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN), 
    array(&$nombre_os, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array(&$nit_os, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array(&$suc_prop_pac, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array(&$cod_pac, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array(&$nombre_pac, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array(&$estado_pac, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array(&$descripcion_motivo_baja,SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
  );

  $sql = "EXEC SP_INSERT_PACIENTE_INHIBIDOS @cod_os = ?, @sucursal = ?, 
                  @nombre_os = ?,@nit_os = ?, @suc_prop_pac= ?,
                  @cod_pac= ?, @nombre_pac= ?, 
                  @estado_pac = ?, @descripciona_motivo_baja= ?";

  $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, $procedure_params);

  if(sqlsrv_execute($stmt)){
    $result = 1;
  }else{
    $result = 0;
  }
}
```

El código funciona bien, pero no logra cargar todo, hay alguna forma de hacer que no tenga que leerlo línea a línea.

Gracias